# In my IOS Project, when i try to remove Bridging Header file cause error?

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

To setup a SideMenu in my iOS project, I'm Using SWRevealViewController without pods and this create a bridging header file

```
SWRevealViewController.h
SWRevealViewController.m
MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h
```

Now I want to remove these three files and add my custom SideMenu, but this cause a big problem 
I trying some solutions which I found in stackoverflow and another websites like 
1. go to Target > Build Settings >  Swift Compiler - General > Objective-c Bridging Header and remove its value. but this case a lot of errors.
 2. retrive just this file 'MyProjectName-Bridging-Header.h' but this again cause a lot of errors.
the project does not work successfully without the three file. although i don't use these three file in any part of my project. 
when I delete the three files + clean the Objective-c Bridging Header I get this error.
[image]

Edit: I note that after I do the deletion step the 'import UIKit' disappears from most files in the project.

Comment: please share the errors

Comment: That's weird. I tried same and that did not happen to me. I used XCode 11.3.

Comment: I fount the solution and I posted it below, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve the problem by the following steps 
1- Delete these two files which caused in creating bridge file

```
SWRevealViewController.h
SWRevealViewController.m
```

2- remove `#import "SWRevealViewController.h"` from Bridging file
 and add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>`

[image]

and this solve the problem for me.

Comment: Worked for me. You should definitely try this if you get obscure UIxxxx is missing kind of errors after removing entries (or the whole file) Bridging-Header.h. Some libraries include UIKit.h for you already, so by removing them, you will no longer get it implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Are these only 3 OBJ-C files you use in your project?

Here are the steps you should follow:
1. Delete all the {{obj-c}}.h,.m,.xib along with AppName-Bridging-Header.h

[image]

2. Then go to Target > Build Settings > Swift Compiler - General > Objective-c Bridging Header and **remove its value**, as you saw in multiple stack overflow post.

[image]

Clean build and run the project to solve the errors

Comment: this did not work for me but I trying another solution which I post it below and it is work.